# Last part from this code is not executing PHP forms

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my first project in php and I am trying to create a form with values from a database.

- 1 First codeblock gives the date `if (!isset($_POST['nieuweBest']))`, works fine,
- 2 Second codeblock by pressing the 'valideren' button i will like to create empty text inputs.
- 3 Third codeblock create view in the database with the data that user entered in the empty text inputs.

So far the first codeblock `if` condition and the second one `else if` works fine, only when pressing the 'valideren' button the last codeblock 'Else' is not creating the asked view.

Also when I cancel the first codeblock `if (!isset($_POST['nieuweBest']))` the view is generated but it only gives me the value of the last text input.

Any suggestions please? I've already been stuck for a few days, thanks in advance.

```
if (!isset($_POST['nieuweBest']))

    {

    $_inhoud=
      "<form method='post' action='$_srv'>
        <h1>Selecteer leveringsdatum</h1>
        <input type='date' name='datum'><br><br>
        <input type='submit' id='nieuweBest' name='nieuweBest' value='Nieuwe Bestelling Toevoegen'>
      </form>";

    }

    else if(!isset($_POST['valideren']))

    {  
      $_date= date('l, d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['datum'])); 
                     
    // verstuur formulier om nieuwe aantals in te geven
      $_inhoud=          
    // $_formulier= 
        "<form method='post' action='$_srv'>
          <h1>Bestelling voor leveringsdatum: $_date</h1>
          <label>Comentaar:</label>
          <input type='text' id='comentaar' name='comentaar'>
          <table border=0>
            <tr>
              <td width=100>Ref</td>
              <td width=500>Omschrijiving</td>
              <td>€VP</td>
              <td>Verw. Hoev.</td>
              <td>Best. Hoev.</td>
              <td width=500>Leverancier</td>
              <td width=500>Familie</td>
            </tr>";
      
      $_query = "SELECT d_prod_naam, d_int_ref, d_familie, d_leverancier
         FROM t_product
         ORDER BY d_familie;
         ";

      $_result = $_PDO -> query("$_query");

      //resultaat van de query verwerken  

      While ($_row = $_result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           
      {
        $_omschrijving= $_row['d_prod_naam'];
        $_intRef= $_row['d_int_ref'];
        $_familie= $_row['d_familie'];
        $_leverancier= $_row['d_leverancier'];
        $_prijs= '€prijs';
        
        
        
          $_inhoud.= "
            <tr>
             <td width=100>$_intRef</td>
             <td width=500>$_omschrijving</td>
             <td>$_prijs</td>
             <td>**</td>
             <td width=10><input type='text' id='aantal'       name='aantal'></td>
             <td width=500>$_leverancier</td>
             <td width=500>$_familie</td>
            </tr>";
                             
          
      
      }
          $_inhoud.= 
           "</table><br><hr>
            <input type='submit' name='valideren' id='inpVal'      value='Valideren'>
            </form>";

    }

    else 
 
    {
          
      $_aantal= $_POST['aantal'];
      $_comentaar= $_POST['comentaar'];
      $_datum_creatie = strftime("%A %d %B %Y - %H:%M:%S");
      $_str="azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn";
      $_shuffled = str_shuffle($_str);

  // create view

  
      $_query= "CREATE VIEW v_$_shuffled AS 
        SELECT d_int_ref,
          d_prod_naam,
          d_familie,
          d_leverancier,
          '$_aantal' AS d_aantal,
          '$_comentaar' AS d_comentaar,
          '$_datum_creatie' AS d_datum_creatie
          FROM t_product
          ORDER BY d_familie;
          ";
  
      $_result= $_PDO->query("$_query");
      
            
      $_inhoud= "
        <br><br><br>
         <h2>view gecreëerd</h2>
         <br><br><br>
         <a href=$_srv>Terug</a>
         ";
    

    }
```

Comment: _“only when pressing the 'validate' button the 'else' part is not executed”_ - which else are you talking about? _“and returns to the beginning of the code”_ - that statement does not even make sense, PHP does not work like that.

Comment: Oh, I see, what you meant was, that it executes the first block of code again after submitting the form. Well, of course it does - your form that contains the “Valideren” button does not have any element by the name `nieuweBest`, so that negated condition of your first if is already true in that case, and therefor it doesn’t go into the else branch.

Comment: I would really rather work with “positive” conditions here, instead of their negation. Plus, you don’t have to use else all the time - you can also just have several if statements just one after the other, as long as their conditions are mutually exclusive, you can achieve the same logic flow, but perhaps a bit easier …

Comment: True CBroe, sorry that my question was not specific enough, in the last block of code I have tried instead of Else an IF code /////// if ($ _POST ['aantal']! = "") and it really works, I think I should rethink the flow of the system with IF's instead of ELSE, I was even thinking about a switch ... I'm going to try it now. Thank you for your comment it was really very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that creating a view inserts data into a database, that is not the case. A view is just a way of storing a query in a database, see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)

What you need to instead is to use INSERT command like this:

```
$_query = "INSERT INTO d_familie ('d_antaal', 'd_commentaar', 'd_datum_creatie') VALUES ($_aantal, '$_comentaar', '$_datum_creatie')"
```

This is assuming that the fields in your database are called d_antaal, d_commentaar and d_datum_creatie.

The date in d_datum_creatie needs to have the correct format: yyyy-mm-dd (if the database field is set to date and not string). Also text and dates need to be put between an apostrophe ('), numbers should not be.

Comment: Good point about the views Fels , but actually if I'm trying to create views instead of Inserts in the data base since those saved data have no effect for other uses in the app, just to export to a pdf document. Thanks for the check.